# ¿Cómo enlazar un enlace interno en WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estuve haciendo mi propio tema y cuando lo creí terminado lo subí a WordPress(en la red no en servidor local), pero me encontré con un problema el cual resulta que al momento de hacer click en el enlace `about us`, dentro del menú me da error 404 o 500, los archivos a los que me refiero están a la raíz del documento y ya he intentado con

```html
<a href="../about-us.php"></a>
<a href="about-us.php"></a>
<a href="/about-us.php"></a>
<a href=/about-us.php/"></a>
<a href="<?bloginfo('template_url')?>/about-us.php"></a>
```

Pero, nada funciona, incluso entré al administrador de archivo de mi host y puse toda la ruta completa en el `href` y no funciona.

Si se requiere más información con gusto se la daré pero por favor necesito que alguien me ayude por que se me acabaron todas las ideas.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress utiliza urls dinámicas y amigables al seo, eso significa que no puede llamar a un archivo php, pues este funciona como plantilla de vista para una pagina, mas no como url o pagina en si, por ende, si tiene una pagina con la url `dominio.com/about` y la plantilla de esa pagina es about.php, la  forma correcta de llamar esa url seria mediante el código, `"<?php bloginfo('url); ?>/about/"`, también puedes usar el ID de la pagina, o bien, el sistema interno de menús de WordPress, generalmente suele ser dinámico, así que es raro que utilicen enlaces estáticos en un sitio web.

Lo recomendable es crear un menú en WordPress y hacer una llamada mediante la función wp_nav_menu(); .