# Se puede enlazar múltiples archivos en wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo una duda sobre wordpress ya que no soy un experto en este tema y he tenido un problema al intentar enlazar algunos archivos.

Supongamos que creo una página web(tengo conocimientos de html, css, JavaScript y php) la cual no es tema, o sea nada está predeterminado. En la raíz del documento tengo un index.php y un about-us.php, lo lógico sería hacer un `<a href=“about-us.php”> About us</a>`lo cual lo he probado en un servidor local y ha funcionado, pero al momento de subirlo a la red a través de wordpress esto no funciona. Mi pregunta es: se puede enlazar dos archivos así en wordpress siendo que mi página no está “adaptada” como un tema para wordpress.

En fin, necesito saber si se puede y si es que se puede entonces que me expliquen cómo hacerlo, además si es que se puede también enlazar scripts de JavaScript.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda y si necesitan más información con gusto la daré

Comment: He respondido tu pregunta, aun así esta parece ser un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420817/c%c3%b3mo-enlazar-un-enlace-interno-en-wordpress por lo que recomendaría eliminar una de las preguntas, tambien te invito a revisar [ask] y hacer el [tour]

Comment: estás subiendo el archivo php por wordpress así como se sube una foto? no debiera dejarte

Answer (score 0):

No se usan archivos php en WordPress como vistas estáticas, si no como plantillas para que puedan ser usado múltiples veces haciendo la web dinámica. para ello en el encabezado de tu plantilla PHP agrega lo siguiente `<?php //Template Name: Agrega un nombre ?>`

Esto declara el archivo como una plantilla de pagina, luego en tu sitio WordPress ve a paginas -> crear nueva pagina y en el apartado de "Atributos de página" ve a plantillas y selecciona el nombre de la plantilla creada, Guarda tu pagina y el enlace que te genere será el enlace que debes de usar para ingresar a esa pagina. Mas información en https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Nota: Parece que no sabes mucho del desarrollo de plantillas para WordPress, por lo que te invito a revisar la documentación oficial de WordPress para la creación de plantillas https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/ o bien sigue la siguiente lista de reproducción de YouTube [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nQZ8YhuCII&list=PLaNBgK4b74m5rKUfdFNPLc43ZuxZeQlC5) donde se explica un poco mas detallado la creación de temas para WordPress

Comment: tengo una duda, yo cree una página web dinámica pero además el index es totalmente diferente al resto de los archivos(about-us, etc) entonces según tu respuesta no puedo hacer eso ya que un tema de wordpress tiene que ser casi lo mismo en todas las páginas, me explico?

Comment: Wordpress tiene plantillas especificas, como index.php, single.php, archive.php, plantillas que directamente repercuten en la vista del sitio, si creaste un index.php seguro visualizas ese archivo en tu sitio sin necesidad de agregar un "Template Name" pero eso no aplica para todos los archivos php que crees, un about-us.php si necesitara un "Template Name para" agregarlo en una pagina de WP, claro, no es necesario que uses el mismo archivo en todas las paginas, pero si que seria posible con el formato correcto

Comment: o sea que tengo que ponerle un Template Name a mi archivo about-us.php, eso se hacía en el archivo style.css, no? Sino agradecería una explicación de como hacerlo. Por otro lado, el archivo about-us.php tiene que estar en la misma raiz del documento en el que está el index.php?

Comment: Amigo, lee las referencias que te deje por favor, este es un tema muy amplio por lo que no es posible explicarlo

Comment: Dale gracias y disculpa

Comment: No nay problema, pero al ser un tema tan amplio, no es posible explicar en esta plataforma por completo, por ello lo mejor es que lo investigues por tu cuenta